# What is the difference between Firebase authentication via native vs web layer in an Ionic/Cordova app?

Tags: firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

When using a Firebase backend to an Ionic/Cordova app, one could authenticate either at the native layer using [Cordova plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-authentication) or at the web layer using the [Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) or [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2). What are some implications of using these either of these approaches?

It seems simpler to keep everything on the web layer as it would enable one to deploy to web or PWA more easily. Are there any compelling reasons to use the native approach?